# updating a multi-textbox from a separate thread that runs a looping UDP Listen in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, udp

I am using C# .net 4.0 VS 2010.

I got a code in a form that basically adds a Task on form load in order to run a UDP Listener (on infinite loop). Whenever the Listener gets something from UDP socket, i add a line and the message to the multiline-textbox (this.textBox4.Text).

However i get an exception saying "Cross-thread operation not valid: "Contol 'textBox4' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

I didn't want to end the loop just to pass the value. Is there a way to do this? Here are my codes:

```
    //main form load menu
    private void frm_Menu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task<int> Listening = DoWorkAsync(1, "OpenYourEars");
        .... // more code here                      
    }

    //async function
    public Task<int> DoWorkAsync(int milliseconds, string WhatToDo)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() =>
        {
            if (WhatToDo == "OpenYourEars")
                goListening();
            ... // more codes here
            return 1;
        });
    }

   //Listening on UDP socket
    public void goListening()
    {
        bool done = false;
        UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
        IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
        string received_data;
        byte[] receive_byte_array;
        try
        {
            while (!done)
            {
                receive_byte_array = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
                received_data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receive_byte_array, 0, receive_byte_array.Length);

                // display on TextBox4
                this.textBox4.Text = "a\r\nb";
                this.textBox4.Text = received_data.ToString().Trim();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //gives "Contol 'textBox4' accessed from a thread other than 
            //the thread it was created on." when receiving a message.
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        listener.Close();
    }
```

Version 2 - After answers by @cremor and @George87

```
    private void frm_Menu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyValue = "Menu,7";
        Task<int> Listening = DoWorkAsync(1, "OpenYourEars");
        .... // more code here                      
    }

    private Task<int> DoWorkAsync(int milliseconds, string WhatToDo)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() =>
        {
            if (WhatToDo == "OpenYourEars")
                goListening();
            .... // more codes here
            return 1;
        });
    }

    //Listening
    private void goListening()
    {
        bool done = false;
        UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
        IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
        string received_data;
        byte[] receive_byte_array;
        try
        {
            while (!done)
            {
                receive_byte_array = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
                received_data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receive_byte_array, 0, receive_byte_array.Length);

                string aa = received_data.ToString().Trim();
                if ( aa != "")
                {
                    SetText("a\r\nb");
                    SetText(received_data.ToString().Trim());
                    aa = "";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());               
        }
        listener.Close();
    }

    private delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        try
        {
              if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
                this.BeginInvoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                SetText(text);
            }
            this.textBox4.Text = text;
        }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
         }

    }
    ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI controls can only be changed by the thread they were created in. You need to check `InvokeRequired` (WinForms) or `Dispatcher.CheckAccess()` (WPF) and then call `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke`.

Comment: It's a lot of reading i hope you don't mind if i take my time. I'll get it eventually. reading this first http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Normally when using c# and use multi threading you should use delegates to make things work and not violate Cross-thread politics. 
In other words  you are not allowed to use objects defined in one thread from other threads. To make this happen you should use delegates to force the owning thread to perform the task for the calling thread.

Instead of:

```
  // display on TextBox4
  this.textBox4.Text = "a\r\nb";
```

you could use this:
define this methods:

```
delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
private void SetText(string text)
{
   if (this.InvokeRequired)
   {
      SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
      this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
   }
   else
   {
      SetText(text);
   }
   this.textBox1.Text = text;     
}
```

and call them from the tread like this

```
SetText("a\r\nb");
```

Comment: Can i pass the textbox4.text value without breaking my loop? I'm a bit new in C# especially in Async.

Comment: Delegates don't magically make things work with multi threading. UI access needs to be done like I explained in my answer, other things need locks or something similar.

Comment: Now that your answer contains some code it is better, but you still should improve your answer text and fix the code to not cause a infinite recursion.

Comment: aye, this asnwer should be:
`if (this.InvokeRequired)
   {
      SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
      this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
   }
   else
   {
      this.textBox1.Text = text; 
   }`

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing your async function to use the current syncronisation context

```
 return Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() =>
    {
        if (WhatToDo == "OpenYourEars")
            goListening();
        return 1;
    },
    new CancellationToken(),
    TaskCreationOptions.None, 
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```